# Why does cms appear in the output?

Tags: tables

[image]

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{makecell}



\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\sfdefault}

\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}



\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{r r}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{LightCyan}
    \thead{Emax/V \\ $\Delta$= $\pm$ 0 V}  & V2 (V) \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    1   & 2 \bigstrut\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 5):

Presumably you want

```
\renewcommand\theadfont{\sffamily}
```

and not

```
\renewcommand\theadfont{\sfdefault}
```

`\sfdefault` holds a font name/identifier (here `cmss`), to actually use sans serif, you need `\sffamily`.

[image: output of code without cmss]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for typesetting units and numbers with units

\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{r r}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{LightCyan}
    \thead{Emax/V \\ $\Delta= \pm 0$\,V}  & V2 (V) \bigstrut\\
    \thead{Emax/V \\ $\Delta= \SI[detect-family]{+-0}{\volt}$}  & V2 (V) \bigstrut\\ % siunitx-alternative
    \hline
    1   & 2 \bigstrut\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Please also change `$\Delta$= $\pm$ 0 V` to `$\Delta=\pm 0$ V`, though. :-)

Comment: @Mico Didn't notice that one, thanks.

Comment: Or perhaps siunitx, those Vs looks like volts